# Load CSV file with 10 columns into an existing BigQuery table that has 103 columns, of which 10 of those have exact column names that of the csv file

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm using python to load a CSV file that has 10 columns into an existing BigQuery table that has 103 columns. Write mode is append. The 10 columns of the CSV file have the exact column name that 10 of the columns of the 103 columns existing BigQuery table. I'm using autodetect=True in job_config for schema auto-detection.

What I want to accomplish is that this python script will write the data into the corresponding columns of the existing BQ table. However, I'm receiving the error "Provided Schema does not match Table".

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you can try to use the [Jagged Row](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv) option to allow to skip the trailing column.

That also mean that the 10 column that you have in your file MUST be the 10 first of your table.

And Of course, I think it's not the case.

---

A usual pattern is to perform that process:

- Upload your file in a temporary table
- Run a query to merge the data in the temporary table into the target table

  - Expert tips: if the column are never the same, you can write a stored procedure that use the information schema and that build a query dynamically. Then use execute immediate to run the merge query
- Delete the temporary table